# Force td to same width as th in table with Fixed header

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table
The table content can change dynamically. Both rows and columns can be added or removed by the user.

The  and  automatically resize to fit the data in a nice way.

[image]
This is what I want it to look like.

But now I've added a fixed header on y-scroll and now the 's doesn't fit the 's. And I can't set the columns to a fixed size because the content can change

[image]

My Html:

```
<div class="table-responsive tableFixedHead">
   <table class="w-100">
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th style="width:5%">#</th>
          <th style="width:60%">Fråga</th>
          <th style="width:5%">Type</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>32</td>
               <td>text</td>
               <td>text</td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>  
 </table>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.tableFixedHead table {
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}

/*
.tableFixedHead {
    width: auto;
}
*/
.tableFixedHead thead {
   background: white;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}

.tableFixedHead tbody {
  height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixedHead tbody tr {
display: table;
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}
```

I've tried different combos of table-layout and display nut can't get it right.

Comment: Please do some proper research - tables with a fixed header are everything but a new topic, you are by far not the first person to try and implement something like that.

Comment: Can you share your HTML table markup? When you add/remove columns do you also add/remove a corresponding `<th>` in the `<thead>`?

Comment: yes I add/remove the th

Comment: I would start by removing all the `display` styles you have in your css. I think changing the default display of your table elements (thead, tbody, tr) will cause more harm than good. You may also want to remove the inline `style` from your `<th>` nodes.

Comment: I think you have to use javascript to update the header column widths as the data column widths change. Implementing this on your own is inviting pain. Find a reusable component someone else has already built. And I agree with @zgood, don't override the `display` properties of the table related elements.